# glDrawBuffers should have flipped IntBuffer?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, framebuffer, fbo

I have the following code:

```
  IntBuffer DrawBuffers = Utils.createIntBuffer(2);
  int bfs[] = {GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      DrawBuffers.put(bfs[i]);
  DrawBuffers.flip();
  GL20.glDrawBuffers(DrawBuffers);
```

If I flip the `IntBuffer` then the `int Status = GL30.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);` don't equal `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`, if I don't flip it then I get the Status right, but I get a black texture instead of the desired texture, I looked throught my code over and over for 2 days now, my best bet is that this part of the code is somehow wrong, the rest seems ok.

Should the `IntBuffer` be flipped before using it in `glDrawBuffers(IntBuffer)` ?

Comment: What status do you get when you flip the buffer?

Comment: Probably `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER` if I had to guess.

Comment: I get: int Status = 36059, how can I get the gl status in the form GL_FRAMEBUFFER_STATUS ?

Comment: **36059** is **0x8CD8**, which is `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DUPLICATE_ATTACHMENT_EXT`. Very weird to be honest, because that error did not make its way into the final FBO specification. At any rate, when you're looking for error codes always look for the error number in hexadecimal.

Comment: Are the errors specified in any file so my app can print the gl error instead of a number? I guess they are.

Comment: btw 36059 is it not 8cdb in hexadecimal ?

Comment: I believe actually the error is 'GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER'

Comment: @user5819: Oops, you're right. My old eyes interpreted the B as an 8 :(

Comment: No problem, btw I solved all the problems with my fbo, thanks all ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, all buffers should be flipped before being passed to LWJGL.

The underlying GL API expects an array for functions that take a Java buffer. The size of that array is a parameter in GL's C language bindings, but hidden from you in Java because LWJGL calculates it as the difference between the current position and the end position.

Unless you flip a `java.nio.Buffer`, which sets the "current" position to the beginning of a buffer, the current position is going to be the end position after calling `put (...)`. Thus, LWJGL passes an array of size **0** to the C-based OpenGL API it sits on top of. If you call `glDrawBuffers (...)` with size **0**, it sets everything to `GL_NONE`, which is definitely going to produce the behavior your described.

Comment: So I should pass it just after doing the last put(..) ?

Comment: @user5819: You must call `flip (...)` after the last `put (...)`. Without it, the current position in your buffer is going to be the end position, and LWJGL won't copy any data.

Comment: Ok, now I understand why I must call flip(), thanks :)